# why is python not adding double quotes after all adb statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    list = ['com.google.android.apps.docs','com.google.android.apps.maps','com.google.android.apps.photos','com.google.android.apps.tachyon','com.google.android.feedback','com.google.android.gms','com.google.android.gms.location.history','com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox','com.google.android.inputmethod.latin','com.google.android.marvin.talkback','com.google.android.music','com.google.android.printservice.recommendation','com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar','com.google.android.tts','com.google.android.videos','com.google.android.youtube','com.google.ar.lens','com.android.vending','com.google.android.gsf']

i = 0
while(i < 1):
 print('\n adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 '.join(list) +'" > CON')
 print('\n')
 i +=
```

output comes as :

```
com.google.android.apps.docs

 adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.apps.maps

 adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.apps.photos

 adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.apps.tachyon

 adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.feedback

 adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.gms

 adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.gms.location.history

 adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox

 adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.inputmethod.latin

 adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.marvin.talkback

 adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.music

 adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.printservice.recommendation

 adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar

 adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.tts

 adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.videos

 adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.youtube

 adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.ar.lens

 adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 com.android.vending

 adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.gsf" > CON


** Process exited - Return Code: 0 **
Press Enter to exit terminal
```

why isn't double quotes and > CON added at end of all adb statements but only at last one ? how to fix it ?

Comment: (Removed the tags _shell_, _android_ and _adb_, because your question is not related to either POSIX shell nor adb nor android. Just because you output a string which contains the text _adb_  somewhere in it, doesn't make it an adb question.

Comment: Oh, sorry I am new here so thought that adb tag might help. I will keep that in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code. This will add each element in list in the given string.

```
list = ['com.google.android.apps.docs','com.google.android.apps.maps','com.google.android.apps.photos','com.google.android.apps.tachyon','com.google.android.feedback','com.google.android.gms','com.google.android.gms.location.history','com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox','com.google.android.inputmethod.latin','com.google.android.marvin.talkback','com.google.android.music','com.google.android.printservice.recommendation','com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar','com.google.android.tts','com.google.android.videos','com.google.android.youtube','com.google.ar.lens','com.android.vending','com.google.android.gsf']

for ele in list:
    print('\n adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 %s" > CON'%ele) #string formatting this puts ele in place of %s
```

Answer (score 0):

why you use `.join()`?? you can simply use `+" some string "+` for this condition it better to use `+`

```
myList = ['com.google.android.apps.docs','com.google.android.apps.maps','com.google.android.apps.photos','com.google.android.apps.tachyon','com.google.android.feedback','com.google.android.gms','com.google.android.gms.location.history','com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox','com.google.android.inputmethod.latin','com.google.android.marvin.talkback','com.google.android.music','com.google.android.printservice.recommendation','com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar','com.google.android.tts','com.google.android.videos','com.google.android.youtube','com.google.ar.lens','com.android.vending','com.google.android.gsf']
for i in myList:
    print('\n adb shell "pm uninstall --user 0 ' + i + '" > CON')
```